# 'import_task' not looping over 'until' loop

Tags: ansible

So I want to loop over the `import_tasks` `until` the somefile last line doesn't contain 10 as a string (the somefile is just output of the script which is printing 1 to 10 with some delay).

**`main.yml`** file

```yaml
 - name: displaying output
   import_tasks : printoutput.yml
   until: output_var.stdout_lines[-1] != '10'
   retries: 30
```

**`printoutput.yml`**

```yaml
- name: print somefile content
  shell: cat /tmp/somefile
  register: output_var
```

somefile

```
1
2
3
4
.
.
10
```

But it is looping over only one time. I don't know how the flow is going. Can you please solve my problem and explain me. Thanks for your help

Comment: What's the use-case? It might be accomplished by other means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: ***"import_task not looping over until loop"***

A: Yes *import_task* completely ignores [*until*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met). For example,

```yaml
shell> cat printoutput.yml
- debug:
    var: completed
```

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        completed: false
    - import_tasks: printoutput.yml
      until: completed|bool

    - set_fact:
        completed: true
    - import_tasks: printoutput.yml
      until: completed|bool
```

give

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  completed: false

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  completed: true

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any way around to do this?

Comment: No. It isn't. Neither `import_tasks nor `include_tasks` accept `until`. Try to describe the use-case in the question if you want to proceed.